# Unstable wifi connection Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, wireless

My wifi connection is very unstable. I have ubuntu 18.04 and the wifi adapter is the ASUS PCE-AC56.

I use the proprietary driver : Broadcom 802.11 Linux STA from source that I installed with the driver manager.

The wifi struggles to connect and the connection drops very frequently. I have a dual boot with Windows and the wifi works perfectly with it.

Do you know how to solve this ?

Thanks !

[Edit] Output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3` :

```
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM4352 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [14e4:43b1] (rev 03)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. BCM4352 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [1043:85ba]
    Kernel driver in use: wl
    Kernel modules: bcma, wl
04:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 26)
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3` terminal command.

Comment: I am afraid nothing else can be done. The driver is installed correctly. It is closed-source and nothing can be tuned.

Comment: Really are you sure ?

It is so annoying

Comment: I have the feeling it started after I plugged in a Bluetooth dongle. It is removed now but the problem persists

Answer (score 1):

Run:

```
sudo gedit /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf
```

and set:

```
wifi.powersave = 0
```

Reboot Ubuntu.